# How to sample a transfer function (angular spectrum) in the frequency domain?

Tags: fft, sampling, dft, time-frequency

I am having this problem in Fourier optics, where I am using the Angular spectrum method (a `lti` filter) to calculate the electric field at the required plane given the distance p and the electric field of another parallel plane.

Essentially I have to implement the following equation for light propagation given in the continuous time domain as a convolution.

```
i_required(x,y) = i_given(x,y)*hp(x,y)
```

Now, my doubt is when computing this using discrete Fourier transforms.

Note the Angular spectrum function is defined only in frequency domain `Hp(fx,fy)`. For ease of explanation sampling of `i_given(x, y)` is done at 1 unit in each dimension.
The steps I am doing:

1. Take DFT2 (Discrete fourier transform along rows and columns) of 
   given samples of `i_given(x, y)` and let it be `I(u, v)` for `u,v = 1:N`
2. Sample the frequency domain of the transfer function `Hp(fx, fy)`
   at `fx = u/N,fy = v/N`
3. Multiply `H(u,v)I(u,v))` and take the IDFT2

What is the consequence of sampling in frequency domain (Step 2)?
Will this cause aliasing in time-domain? Ways to mitigate effects if any?